# web service API in grails

Tags: web-services, grails

'My requirement in application is to implement web service that accepts json response and bind the data elements to the domain in our application and then save to database. some blogs suggesting to define controller actions with the URI in the URLMappings.groovy file or another option is to represent domain as Rest Resource annotation.

I have written the following code in my Grails controller class for the given requirement and let me know if any other configurations needed to for the others to access this end point

```
json response:
-------------
{
  "orderId": 1,
  "orderDateTime": "07/10/2020",
  "orderTypeId": 1,
  "SiteId":  "5"
}

Order Controller:
----------------
    static allowedMethods = [
            saveOrder: ["GET","POST"]
    ]

   def saveOrder() {
        def m=[:]
        def orderJson = request.JSON
        def orderInstance = new Order()
        orderInstance.properties = orderJson

        try {
            m.id = orderService.saveOrder(orderInstance)
            if(m.id)
                m.successMsg = "Successfully created Order for ......."
        }
        catch(e) {
            log.error("Error creating Order",e)
            render status:"An error occurred while processing your request.  This order 
    HAS NOT been processed."
            return
        }
    render m as JSON
}
```

\\

Comment: It is unclear to me what the question is.  One small thing is it would be unusual to configure `saveOrder` to accept `GET` requests if the action expects the request to have a body which contains JSON.  `saveOrder: 'POST'` probably makes more sense.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I just need to Implement webservice in Grails 3.xx version that accepts json rsponse and save in our database. So saveOrder method defining in static allowed methods block with POST will be enough to access our web service?

Comment: "So saveOrder method defining in static allowed methods block with POST will be enough to access our web service?" - What `static allowedMethods = [saveOrder: 'POST']` means is if a request is made to that controller action using any HTTP verb other than `POST`,  your code won't be executed and a 405 will be returned to the client.  That is really the only role that `allowedMethods` plays.

Comment: Thanks @JeffScottBrown. what are the steps to implement the  RESTFUL webservice in grails. I need to provide saveOrder method as end point to our application for our partners to access and they will be sending json as a POST request